# concatenate components and text in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to concatenate a Component react with other component or with a text ?

I trying this:

`conts foo = { <ComponentA/> + "hello world" }`

When I put `foo` as a parameter to an atributte:

`<OtherComponent content={foo}/>`

Is render:

> `<Object type> hello world`

Comment: I think you’re looking for [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), added in 16.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
const foo = (
  <React.Fragment>
    <ComponentA/> hello world
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just mean to compose a new component out of two others?

```
const ComposedComponent = () => (
<>
   <ComponentA />
   <ComponentB />
   <h1>Some text</h1>
</>
)
```